# QGIS shortest line between features cannot return 0,0?

Tags: qgis, distance, shortest-path

I have been out measuring railway tracks. I need to find any deviations from a straight line on the individual rails. I have created a line between the first and last point in my measurement (snapping to the points), which will be the line I use as the destination layer (centre line).

[image]

I use 'Shortest line between features' to calculate the distance between the points and the centre line. The calculations look correct, except for the first and last points (where the centre line starts and stops). I would expect a result of 0.0 but get distances that are way off? I can leave these two points out and get the results I want, but I find it strange that the function cannot return a zero.

This should be 0,0:

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: It can return 0. Zoom/show the suspicious distance line, maybe it will help (ex: hidden point, line doesn't start at the last point etc)

Comment: I have tried zooming all the way in and searching for hidden lines/points etc. I found no solution here. The funny thing is that when I asked QGIS to zoom to one of the endpoints, nothing happened? Regardless, I have come up with a solution. When I don't use snapping to start and end the centre line, I get the result I expected - i.e. (almost) 0 in the endpoints.